# Firefox logs invalid URL?

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-addon, location

I'm writing an extension for firefox. Using dom.location to keep track of visited search results pages, i'm getting this url http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=642c18fb4411ca2e . If you click it, the google search results for "hi" should come up. You'll know that from the title bar - because the rest of the page won't load. This happens with any google search. Oddly enough, if you cut part of it off, so say, http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hi - it works! But Googling "hi" myself does give me a longish URL - http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=db658cc5049dc510 . I know for a fact that the first time that URL was visited, the page loaded, I did it myself.

Can anyone make reason out of this?

**I just tried my experiment again, this time saving the original URL in the location bar. It turns out, dom.location.href is giving a different value. How is this happening?**

Original:
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=642c18fb4411ca2e

dom.location.href
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=642c18fb4411ca2e

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);

var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
    if(appcontent)
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    var messagepane = document.getElementById("messagepane"); // mail
    if(messagepane)
      messagepane.addEventListener("load", function () { myExtension.onPageLoad(); }, true);
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
    // do something with the loaded page.
    // doc.location is a Location object (see below for a link).
    // You can use it to make your code executed on certain pages only.


var url = doc.location.href;

if (url.match(/(?:p|q)(?:=)([^%]*)/)) {alert("MATCH" + url);resultsPages.push(url);} else {alert(url);
  }
}
```

**This snippet  comes directly from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/On_page_load) with the matching and alerts my own. I apologize for not posting the code earlier.**

Comment: my answer stands even after your edit. You're likely getting a load event for a frame inside the main document in addition to the load event for the main document. Googling should find the way to distinguish the two -- it's a faq.

Comment: I will continue to research this on my own as I have been, but I don't see how that can be the problem. I have tried every single url that is logged. I understand that one of them is a "false" url - the frame - but I fail to see how not one of them can take me to the search.

Comment: Did you check that the right URL is not filtered by your regexp?

Comment: this is an already tested regex. however, because I had the same concern, if you look at the code, I have it show it an alert either way, (one just appends "MATCH" and adds it to the list as well). I have noticed that there is an extra url when you click a result (the forwarding url), but I am now testing without even clicking a link, just loading the search page. I am given only one URL. The process is - reload chrome (about:blank), click homepage (google.com), enter "test" (MATCHhttp://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=test&aq=f&aqi=g10&oq=&fp=aa7ac5834e645580). That's everything

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the "right" page http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=1&cad=b there seems to be a frame with the "wrong" location: frames[0].location == "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=1&cad=b". You're probably getting the inner frame's location. I have no idea why, since you didn't post any of your code and just mention some "dom.location", which I never heard of.